# Ajax query for script loading is running only once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a javascript script to send an ajax request. The PHP script sends back text which will be inserted in a script markup.
The problem is that it works only once. The script works. But when I do another clic on my button, the result of the script doesn't change (in fact, my PHP script returns a random number).

My code is here below. I hope that I'm clear...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
        {
        $('#submit').bind('click', function(){request(useData)});
            });

    // fonction pour la requête ajax
    var xhr =null;
    function request(callback)
        {
        if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 0)
            {
            xhr.abort(); // On annule la requête en cours !
            }
        // instanciation (globale) de l'objet pour l'envoi de la requête
        xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0))
                {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
                }
            else if (xhr.readyState < 4)
                {
                document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "inline";
                }
            };

        // définition et protection des variables
        var title = encodeURIComponent($('#title').val()) ;
        // envoi
        xhr.open('POST', 'generate.php', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send('title=' + title);

        // juste pour voir quand la requête a été executée - a enlever en prod
        $('#test').text(Math.random()+title);
        }

    // fonction pour le traitement des éléments reçus
    function useData(sData)
        {
        $('#scriptGraph').text(sData);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit">




    <script id="scriptGraph" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As requested, I add the code of the PHP page en the code of getXMLHttpRequest() function.
PHP:

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'] ;
echo "alert('".$title.rand()."');" ;
?>
```

Function to instance XHR:

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
var xhr = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } else {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    }
} else {
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
    return null;
}

return xhr;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Extra information: the Google Chrome Console shows that the request is send each time I click on the button. The problem is so at the script markup. Maybe the browser doesn't take into account the changes in the markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem! I have to eval the result of the Ajax query.

So my code to use the result of the Ajax query is:

```
function useData(sData)
{
eval(sData);
}
```

I didn't try but I think another solution would be: deleting the script markup and create a new one each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It course you are aborting AJAX Object

`xhr.abort();` // On annule la requête en cours !

Comment: I get it! Thank you. I added that to prevent multiple request sending. However, the result is the same if I delete this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (xhr && xhr.readyState != 0)
            {
            xhr.abort(); // On annule la requête en cours !
            }
```

[See this.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)

`readyState` is only null when `request not initialized` which is the first time only. Try playing with that although it might not be the case.

Comment: Thank you! I tried by extending the condition with "if (xhr && (xhr.readyState != 0 || shr.readyState != 4))" but nothing changes.

Comment: That's because most of the time your state will be `4` as `finished and ready`, because the other states last a very short time. If you want to prevent multiple requests you should write a clause which aborts the function if there are more than lets say 3 requests in 3 seconds or so.

Comment: I will find another system to prevent multiple request (disabling the button). But if I delete this part of the code, it still not working.

Comment: Could you add the `php` code from the `generate.php` file and any other that is associated with the function?

Comment: Done. Thank you for taking time to help me.

Comment: No problem :). I noticed that you send a request like this: `xhr.send('title=' + title);` and then in `php` you use `$title = $_POST['title'] ;`. There might be a problem, because every time you call the function it adds the `title` value to the link. Maybe you should reset it after every use? E.g if your `title` value is `a` then after every time it will add `a` to it and after lets say 3 times your `title` will be `aaa`.

Comment: I have to reset the value in PHP or javascript?

Comment: You just need to reset your link after you're done with the function. Doesn't matter whether php or JS. Just check your link after you press the button. It has `title=...` at the end right? Well you need to reset it's value or completely remove the `title`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51024/discussion-between-user3461434-and-descampsau)